# Same-Origin error when using iframe code copied from vimeo/youtube

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I created a slideshow for a website and users can put videos from vimeo or youtube in it. It works just fine. Due to some limitations with current browsers I have the thumbnail of the video showing in the slideshow, and clicking the picture opens a lightbox with the actual video. I copied the `iframe` code from both the youtube and vimeo websites exactly as they have it, but my console is showing errors for every `iframe` on the page. This is an example `iframe` element on my page:

```
<iframe
    class="hide_me"
    src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7339803"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    frameborder="0"
    webkitallowfullscreen=""
    mozallowfullscreen=""
    allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```

And this is the error I'm getting in my console:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://player.vimeo.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://my-machine-name". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: seems to work fine for me you would only get that message if you were trying to ajax the url http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Hap/

Answer (score 0):

Pages can prevent themselves being loaded inside iframes on third party sites (same origin policy).

The whole rundown can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Pages that allow embedding in general often have a specific URL without these restrictions, but even YouTube has added them to their current embed URL recently with the old /embed/ scheme still working. Maybe Vimeo also has a working alternative?